# Openxml, excel truncating leading zeros

Tags: c#, openxml

I am exporting excel using openxml, I have a scenario to show a column with data "0001" for that I used below code,

```
c = new Cell();
c.DataType=CellValues.String;
c.CellValue = new CellValue("0001");
```

While opening excel my cell contains the value as I expected ("0001"). But after selecting the cell and move out from the same, the value changes from "0001" to "1". In excel the cell type is "General" instead of text.

How can I fix this

Comment: try to pass value like `new CellValue("=\"0001\"")`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving an apostrophe `'` in front of the value, like this:

```
c = new Cell();
c.DataType=CellValues.String;
c.CellValue = new CellValue("'0001");
                             ^^
```

Comment: it will work for the existing item, but if a user enter for eg: "003" in another cell then excel trim leading zeros. I need to change all the cells in column to type 'Text'. Is that possible